# How do I get the game to stop thinking I have Junk that I don't have?

Tags: fallout-4, mods

There's a glitch in Fallout 4 where the workshop is saying I have junk when I don't, how do I remedy the glitch?

Mods used in order:

1. Vilance's Library support plugin
2. What's your name
3. Sanctuary doors
4. Vault 88 New Rooms (removing this causes worse problems than this glitch)
5. Vault 144 player Settlement
6. the F4SE Loader

Comment: Has the mod list changed in any way since you started your current save file? Additions are somewhat okay mid game. Removing any is not, nor is running loot after starting a game. Also; never anything but problems with interior vaults or those you have to unlock. Get rid of all the 'vault' stuff, stop building inside, forget about the airport, and start a new game. *After* you decide you're not going to 'mod' for a while - at least for the rest of this play through.

Comment: And you're missing like at least ten mods that make the game *work* in the first place. MCM? The patch? ~100 QoL improvements.... - It's prob Vilance's : "ESL file to support my **mods using shared workshop assets**." - Shared assets and interior vaults that span two cells? that's asking for trouble.

Comment: *bat mat* - Batch File all the junk https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/68/ - I try not to use that but then I go, *this is stupid*. - It's mod number *68* out of ~50k for crying out loud.

Comment: @Mazura I'm probably am, I'm just mentioning what's on the mod load order screen, and F4SE loader